# Merging two contingency tables

Tags: r

I have two contigency tables generated using `table()`.

```
R> first
0   5  11  17  19  50  95 100 
48   1   1   1   1   1   1   6

R> second
0  11  17  30  33  50  67  83 100 
67   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   8
```

I want to fill both tables with missing elements with 0 frequency. For instance, I want these to look like this:

```
R> first
0  5  11  17  19  30  33  50  67  83  95 100 
48  1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   6

R> second
0  5  11  17  19  30  33  50  67  83  95 100 
67  0   1   1   0   1   1   2   2   2   0   8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. First option**

We could convert the vector to factor class specifying the levels and then do the `table`.  In the example created ie. the `table` output, some elements of 'v1' are missing in 'first'

```
  first
  # 0   5  11  17  19  50  95 100 
  #48   1   1   1   1   1   1   6
```

Suppose, if we go back to get the initial vector, convert that to factor by specify the `levels` as 'v1' before calling the `table`

```
   table(factor(rep(names(first), first), levels=v1))
   #  0   5  11  17  19  30  33  50  67  83  95 100 
   #48   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   6
```

The same thing can be done for 'second'

**2. Second option**

Instead of going back and changing the 'factor' levels, we could also use get the desired output by creating a 'third' table with '0s' for all the unique elements, conctenate both the table, remove the duplicate elements, sort..

```
 Un <- union(names(first), names(second))
 third <- as.table(setNames(rep(0, length(Un)), Un))
 first1 <- c(first, third)
 first2 <- first1[!duplicated(names(first1))]
 as.table(first2[order(as.numeric(names(first2)))])
 #   0   5  11  17  19  30  33  50  67  83  95 100 
 #  48   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   6
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(0, 5, 11, 17, 19, 30, 33, 50, 67, 83, 95, 100)
first <- structure(c(48, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6), .Dim = 8L, 
.Dimnames = list(
c("0", "5", "11", "17", "19", "50", "95", "100")), class = "table")

second <- structure(c(67, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 8), 
.Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = list(
 c("0", "11", "17", "30", "33", "50", "67", "83", "100")), 
 class = "table")
```

Comment: It was foolish of me to not mention this. Anyways, I can work with this. Thanks.

Comment: @Potato_head I think I got what you wanted.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a ton! You just solved two of my problems in one swing, nice! :)